# Is there a name for a function that leaves a subset of its input unchanged? And how to write it as a composition?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Is there a name for functions $f: \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Z} \to \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$ that map $(x, z) \mapsto (x, y)$, i.e. that map part of the input to itself and then applies a transformation to $z$.

Also, how do you write this as a composition of functions?

My first idea would be to define $g: \mathcal{Z} \to \mathcal{Y}$ such that $ z \mapsto y$ and the identity $\text{id}_x: \mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{X}$ that maps $x$ to itself and then maybe define
$$
f := [\text{id}_x, g]^\top
$$

Comment: It's fine. More commonly we write ${\rm id}\times g$ for $f$.